# WPF Why does this Textblock show a newline at the beginning?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, textblock

So I have created a custom class deriving from `TextBlock` in order to filter a Formula like "value^5" into something renderable (see [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63781024/regex-filtering-formatted-string)).

Now, this works just fine. The so-called `LatexBlock` (custom `TextBlock`) successfully captures the parts of the Inlines I want to put in as subscript and superscript. Like here in this picture:

[image: correct rendering of desired formula]

This gets generated with the following code:

```
        block.Text = "";
        block.Inlines.Clear();
        block.Inlines.Add(new Run(text, block.ContentStart) { BaselineAlignment = BaselineAlignment.Baseline});
        block.Inlines.Add(new Run(sub) { BaselineAlignment = System.Windows.BaselineAlignment.Subscript });
        block.Inlines.Add(new Run(super) { BaselineAlignment = System.Windows.BaselineAlignment.Superscript});
```

Where `text`, `sub` and `super` are the captured groups from the regex (see other question linked above). Now, the weird behavior I encounter is, that there is an empty line at the beginning of the textblock? This can easily be seen on this picture:

[image: textblock with bounds]

As you can see, the bounds of the `TextBlock` dont match the content. Does anyone have an idea, why that happens here? I already tried to explicitly set the `TextPointer` of the first `Run` to the `TextBlock`s `ContentStart` but that didn't make any difference.

Comment: That's probably space reserved / assigned to the `super` text... can you just not add the inline if there is no super text, does that work?

Comment: I bet that's not a 'new line' but rather an over-calculated Height of the textblock's itself. Check its .Text (or whatever else you are using instead of Text.. Inlines?), if it doesn't start with \n (or some otherwise empty line) then there's no newline there. And that would mean, that the TextBlock tries to reserve space for something that's not there. Since it's your custom LatextBlock, then either you have an error in math, or you've set some layouting options wrong. A bit hard to guess by looking how you use your component, and not how the component does its things..

Comment: @BiesiGrr That was the problem. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Biesi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5351370/biesi-grr)s Comment I figured it out. Its the space reserved for a superscripted text, which will be reserved even if the text is empty.

Adding `if(super != "")` before the Inline-Add gives the right output.